# Create Folder on installation of Outlook Office Add-ins

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've been working with the Office Add-ins JavaScript API and managed to develop an Outlook plugin following the steps outlined in this guide: [Outlook Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/outlook-tutorial).

Now, I'm looking to enhance my plugin by creating a folder upon installation. Any guidance or examples on achieving this with the Office Add-ins JavaScript API would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Office JS (JavaScript API for Outlook) doesn't provide anything for that. Moreover, Outlook/Office web add-ins like any other web applications have a very limited access to the disk and operate isolated (in a sandbox) for security reasons. They also don't provide any custom actions prior installation.